# What does `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log ` mean?

Tags: web-services, security, unix, frontend, digital-ocean

I learn the course Full Stack for Frontend Engineers on frontendmaster.

I use a Digital Ocean server. I disabled root access by setting `PermitRootLogin no` and added my public key to the `authorized_key` file so I can log in.

then: 
`sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

```
Oct  7 08:42:17 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16857]: Invalid user user from 74.208.145.162
Oct  7 08:42:17 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16857]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:17 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16857]: Connection closed by 74.208.145.162 port 58905 [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:23 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16859]: Invalid user ubnt from 74.208.145.162
Oct  7 08:42:23 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16859]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubnt [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:23 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16859]: Connection closed by 74.208.145.162 port 59157 [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:26 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16861]: Connection closed by 74.208.145.162 port 59446 [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:31 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16863]: Invalid user admin from 74.208.145.162
Oct  7 08:42:31 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16863]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:32 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16863]: Connection closed by 74.208.145.162 port 59670 [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:33 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16865]: Invalid user support from 74.208.145.162
Oct  7 08:42:33 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16865]: input_userauth_request: invalid user support [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:34 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16865]: Connection closed by 74.208.145.162 port 59872 [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:39 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16867]: Invalid user admin from 74.208.145.162
Oct  7 08:42:39 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16867]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Oct  7 08:42:40 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01-fem-young sshd[16867]: Connection closed by 74.208.145.162 port 59944 [preauth]
```

Does this mean I was hacked? If so what can I do to protect myself?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The sudo command let end user to act like root user.

To disable sudo access you need to edit your `/etc/sudoers` file.

Example
Following entry in `sudoers` file let test user to execute any command , as any user from any terminal.

```
test ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Disable sudo for test user you may comment above entry from `/etc/sudoers`.